# Unity UI, 2D Game to Main Menu, timescale issue

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, unity-game-engine

So basically, I have the Main Menu and a 2D Game...

once I click start from the main menu, the 2d game runs fine, but when I go back to the main menu from the game and start it again it is in a paused state, the main character reacts only to user input and changes animation but doesn't move. so I have to click ESC again...

could you please help me fix

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "paused state"? Do you ever adjust the timescale in your code?

Comment: @GamesSwitch Most probably you are not resetting TimeScale to 1 on start of your game. 
OR it can be a static variable whose value remains saved during session regardless of moving from scene to scene.

Comment: What changes do you make when you pause and start again?